# xrandr not showing all ports and resolutions

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I recently installed a new Nvidia driver, 390.87 for my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS machine.

[image]

Now, I can't connect external monitors over DP anymore - they're just not recognized and stay dark.

`xrandr` doesn't show the DP port anymore:

`Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1600 x 900, maximum 16384 x 16384
LVDS-1-1 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 174mm
   1600x900      60.00 +  59.99*   59.94    59.95    59.82

   1440x900      59.89

   1400x900      59.96    59.88

   1440x810      60.00    59.97

   1368x768      59.88    59.85

   1360x768      59.80    59.96

(...)
VGA-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)`

What should I do?

*EDIT: Some more information*:

My `/etc/X11/Xorg.conf` is empty, which may be the at the root of the problem. The reason for this is that, whenever I run `sudo nvidia-xconfig` to write a new `Xorg.conf`, I cannot login anymore, i.e. when I reboot the machine and enter my password at the login screen, the mouse cursor freezes. I can then change to another tty, but not start a graphical interface. The Linux graphics system is just so complicated...

How can I even start debugging this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by following this answer to a similar question on [ubuntuforums.org](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2403455):

Disabling NVIDIA KMS (enabled by default in 390.77) resolves the issue:

```
Edit /lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-kms.conf file and set modeset to 0:
options nvidia-drm modeset=0
```

Save, update initramfs and reboot:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

reboot

Comment: This resolved my issue as well (I in fact have the same laptop model as the OP on the ubuntuforms.org post.)